# Creating a Trigger to delete from table when deleting duplicate rows from another related table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I 'am using sqlserver ,I created Trigger to delete from YTable, when I deleted duplicate rows from Xtable.
Note : YTable has a foreign key from XTable as On_ID

Trigger Query

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterDeletev4 ON XTable

 AFTER DELETE
 AS
 declare @empid int;

 select @empid=d.[On_ID] from deleted d; 

 Delete from YTable
 where [On_ID]= @empid
 PRINT 'AFTER DELETE TRIGGER fired.'
```

delete duplicate rows from XTable

```
WITH C AS(
   SELECT  *,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY [col1] ORDER BY [col2])
   FROM [Sourcing].[src].XTable
  )
  DELETE FROM C WHERE RN > 1
```

The Result

> (0 row(s) affected)   AFTER DELETE TRIGGER fired.
>
> (1271060 row(s) affected)

please what's the wrong of these Queries

thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statement

```
select @empid=d.[On_ID] from deleted d
```

will not work correctly in the case when you're deleting more then one record from `XTable` since you can't place multiple IDs into single integer variable.

You can simply change your delete statement in trigger to

```
 Delete from YTable
 where [On_ID] in (select [On_ID] from deleted)
```